# outline generated from browser on focus

Tags: css, focus, outline

On some div with class ng-scope the browser added

```css
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

This generate a very bad looking style. How can I get rid of it. Many tell to not remove it :
[link](http://www.outlinenone.com/)

[image: ugly]

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove this you can use the following snippet:

```
:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

There is good reason as to why you should not remove the focus outline, much of it collected in the link you provided, but in some cases you can highlight focused elements in a different way.

The general rule is, in my opinion, if you provide your own way of highlighting the element, there is no harm in removing the outline. In many cases you can combine your `:hover` and `:focus` declarations.